# Display a permanent frame or sub window of information on any webpage

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am wanting to develop an app for chrome, which can display useful things the user places on it and also access the web page content.

It is a little like a frameset: my app would be the top frame (say) and be about 2 - 3 inches high. The main window will be the actual document - what ever it might be. I realize I cannot actually do this with frames because many pages will complain about being loaded into a frame.

I thought it might be possible to do this using a chrome extension. Most of the extensions I have seen only bring up a pop up window, which closes when the user clicks away.

I would want the popup to remain and also not overlap onto the main page.

I have looked a JS injection but cannot make head nor tail if that is going to do what I want and don't really want to put in hours of figuring it out only to find it cannot (if I don't have too).

Has anyone any ideas if this is feasible with an extension or not? Or perhaps there is another google / chrome feature I could use.

Many thanks for any help.

Ian

Comment: before asking, look at the chrome extensions documentation, you have only looked at existing extensions. read about content scripts.

Answer (score 1):

There's no API to do that. Some extensions open a popup and sync its position to *stick* next to the browser at all times, so that's the closest you can get, safely.

You could try injecting your banner in all pages and push the content down, but it's going to break in many complex websites

Answer (score 0):

[bfred.it's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38140274/934239) covers extension side pretty well. You can inject UI into the page, but this will invariably break SOME site's layout.

As for Chrome App side, the closest you get is this [browser sample](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/webview-samples/browser). You can embed any page in a [`<webview>` element](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview) in a Chrome App, and it won't be subject to frame restrictions, but your "browser" **will be fully independent from the main Chrome browser**.

It'll run in a separate window, will have a separate state (cookies, etc.), will have no integration with Chrome's autofill/password storage, and you'll need to implement browser controls and some functions yourself from scratch.

That's probably not what you want, but that's the design philosophy of Chrome Apps - they are *independent* of the browser, which only provides a runtime environment for them.